# Michael Hartl Ruby on Rails tuttorial chapter9 Rspec Fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Hi i'm a newbie to Rails. [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users?version=3.2#top) Chapter 9, Rspec faild. rails ver. was 3.2.6. This source is [github](https://github.com/ichisemasashi/sample_app).  I have 3 failing tests to complete the Chapter.

Terminal returns this:

```
  $ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb
    ......F.FF.................

Failures:

  1) User pages index pagination should list each user
     Failure/Error: page.should have_selector('li', text: user.name)
       expected css "li" with text "Person 41" to return something
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:44:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:43:in `each'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:43:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) User pages delete links as an admin user 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_link('delete', href: user_path(User.first)) }
       expected link "delete" to return something
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:61:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) User pages delete links as an admin user should be able to delete another user
     Failure/Error: expect { click_link('delete') }.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       no link with title, id or text 'delete' found
     # (eval):2:in `click_link'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:63:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:63:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 4.6 seconds
27 examples, 3 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:42 # User pages index pagination should list each user
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:61 # User pages delete links as an admin user 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:62 # User pages delete links as an admin user should be able to delete another user
```

Spec File is This:

```
$ cat spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "index" do

    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

    before(:all) { 30.times { FactoryGirl.create(:user) } }
    after(:all)  { User.delete_all }

    before do
      sign_in user
      visit users_path
    end

    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'All users') }
    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'All users') }

    describe "pagination" do

      it { should have_selector('div.pagination') }

      it "should list each user" do
        User.paginate(page: 1).each do |user|
          page.should have_selector('li', text: user.name)
        end
      end

    before do
      sign_in FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      FactoryGirl.create(:user, name: "Bob", email: "bob@example.com")
      FactoryGirl.create(:user, name: "Ben", email: "ben@example.com")
      visit users_path
    end

    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'All users') }
    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'All users') }

    it "should list each user" do
      User.all.each do |user|
        page.should have_selector('li', text: user.name)
      end
    end
  end
end

    describe "delete links" do

      it { should_not have_link('delete') }

      describe "as an admin user" do
        let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }
        before do
          sign_in admin
          visit users_path
        end

        it { should have_link('delete', href: user_path(User.first)) }
        it "should be able to delete another user" do
          expect { click_link('delete') }.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
        end
        it { should_not have_link('delete', href: user_path(admin)) }
      end
    end

  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: user.name) }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
  end

  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign up') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign up')) }
  end

  describe "signup" do

    before { visit signup_path }

    let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      it "should not create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      before do
        fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
        fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
        fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
        fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
      end

      it "should create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
      end

      describe "after saving the user" do
        before { click_button submit }
        it { should have_link('Sign out') }
      end
    end
  end

  describe "edit" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before do
      sign_in user
      visit edit_user_path(user)
    end
    describe "page" do
      it { should have_selector('h1',    text: "Update your profile") }
      it { should have_selector('title', text: "Edit user") }
      it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
    end

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Save changes" }

      it { should have_content('error') }
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      let(:new_name)  { "New Name" }
      let(:new_email) { "new@example.com" }
      before do
        fill_in "Name",             with: new_name
        fill_in "Email",            with: new_email
        fill_in "Password",         with: user.password
        fill_in "Confirm Password", with: user.password
        click_button "Save changes"
      end

      it { should have_selector('title', text: new_name) }
      it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success') }
      it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
      specify { user.reload.name.should  == new_name }
      specify { user.reload.email.should == new_email }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Kind of late, but maybe this can helps others as helping me.

My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18667110/1223901)

I guess this resolve the 2 and 3 fails.

Regards