# Stuck on ROR tutorial CH 9 Ex. 9

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am stuck and cannot figure out where I am going wrong.  I have found similar topics but no solutions to these errors:

1) User pages delete links as an admin user admin visiting index page

```
 Failure/Error: it { should have_link('delete', href: user_path(User.first)) }
   expected link "delete" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:127:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

2) User pages delete links as an admin user admin visiting index page should be able to delete another user

```
 Failure/Error: expect { click_link('delete') }.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   no link with title, id or text 'delete' found
 # (eval):2:in `click_link'
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:129:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:129:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Test Code

```
describe "delete links" do

  it { should_not have_link('delete') }
  describe "as an admin user" do
    let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }
      before do
        sign_in admin
        visit users_path
      end

      it { should have_link('delete', href: user_path(User.first)) }
      it "should be able to delete another user" do
      expect { click_link('delete') }.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
    end
    it { should_not have_link('delete', href: user_path(admin)) }
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
 def
   User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User destroyed."
    redirect_to users_url
  end
```

Index:

```
<% provide(:title, 'All users') %>
<h1>All users</h1>

<%= will_paginate %>

<ul class="users">
  <%= render @users %>
</ul>

<%= will_paginate %>
```

Partial

```
<li>
  <%= gravatar_for user, size: 52 %>
  <%= link_to user.name, user %>
  <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
    | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                                  data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

Any guidance/help would be greatly appreciated....

Comment: what's the name and path of the partial? what does `puts page.body` after `visit users_path` show?

Comment: You can add a `save_and_open_page` to confirm, but I bet you don't have any `@users` to render; so there's no delete link showing. Confirm?

Comment: prusswan,  thank you for the feedback, the partial is _user.html.erb and is located in the views/users folder.  I am not sure where you are seeing puts page.body

Comment: Jesse,Thanks for the help.  I do have users, i even saw that as a solution to a similar thread, but i confirmed that was not the case.

Comment: I think the problem is that in the test it is never actually visiting the users_path, even                                it { should have_selector('h1', text: "All users") }
fails........

Comment: Prusswan, You were correct. I thought that when i ran db:test:prepare it would populate the users i had in the table, now i realize that is not the case, and i need to populate them in the test, the solution was to add:                                                                before(:all) { 30.times { FactoryGirl.create(:user) } }
after(:all)  { User.delete_all }                                                                                                                                            My only question is, how come i can delete the admin user if i access from the console???

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I came one year later, but I just stated to learn Ruby on Rails from the same tutorial ([Rails tutorial from Michael Hartl](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/)) and face on the same problem.

Here what I found and how can I did to fix (thanks to our mates commets, I went through the page source code and found the problem.):

From the tutorial, [Listing 9.43](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#code-delete_link_tests) says:

> require 'spec_helper'
>
> describe "User pages" do
>
> subject { page }
>
> describe "index" do
>
> ```
> let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
>
> before do
>   sign_in user
>   visit users_path
> end
>
> it { should have_title('All users') }
> it { should have_content('All users') }
>
> describe "pagination" do
>   .
>   .
>   .
> end
>
> describe "delete links" do
>
>   it { should_not have_link('delete') }
>
>   describe "as an admin user" do
>     let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }
>     before do
>       sign_in admin
>       visit users_path
>     end
>
>     it { should have_link('delete', href: user_path(User.first)) }
>     it "should be able to delete another user" do
>       expect do
>         click_link('delete', match: :first)
>       end.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
>     end
>     it { should_not have_link('delete', href: user_path(admin)) }
>   end
> end   end   .   .   . end
> ```

Check how the section related to "delete links" is after the "pagination" section.
The pagination explanation starts in [Listing 9.33](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#code-will_paginate_test), and has the next code:

> require 'spec_helper'
>
> describe "User pages" do
>
> subject { page }
>
> describe "index" do
>       let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
>       before(:each) do
>         sign_in user
>         visit users_path
>       end
>
> ```
> it { should have_title('All users') }
> it { should have_content('All users') }
>
> describe "pagination" do
>
>   before(:all) { 30.times { FactoryGirl.create(:user) } }
>   after(:all)  { User.delete_all }
>
>   it { should have_selector('div.pagination') }
>
>   it "should list each user" do
>     User.paginate(page: 1).each do |user|
>       expect(page).to have_selector('li', text: user.name)
>     end
>   end
> end   end   .   .   . end
> ```

I realize that the `after(:all) { User.delete_all }` statement erase ALL records from the test db after of that section (let me continue, because this is so obvious :P ). When the RSpec test continues to "delete links" there are any user created.

The next step is to create a new 'admin' user, and is the only one in the test DB at this point. As is expected the:

> it { should have_link('delete', href: user_path(User.first)) }

will be fail because the current user can't delete itself, and it not has any 'delete' link. In the same way the next test will be fail too:

> click_link('delete', match: :first)

The solution (Workaround or w/e :D ):

I believe there are some ways to resolve this, I think in two (no. 1 is the one that I used)

A. I add a non-admin user, before the admin user try to login, this let me have 2 users into the test DB, as the follow code:

> describe "delete links" do
>       it { should_not have_link('delete') }
>
> ```
> describe "as an admin user" do
>     let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }
>     before do
>         FactoryGirl.create(:user, name: "test", email: "test@example.com")
>         sign_in admin
>         visit users_path
>     end
>
>     it { should have_link('delete', href: user_path(User.first)) }
>     it "should be able to delete another user" do
>         expect do
>             click_link('delete', match: :first)
>         end.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
>     end
>     it { should_not have_link('delete', href: user_path(admin)) }
> end   end
> ```

The statement `FactoryGirl.create(:user, name: "test", email: "test@example.com")` did the work.

B. Move all the "delete links" section before the "pagination" section, because I guess in that point, exists at least the first user created in the begin of the ***user_pages_spec.rb***.

That's it, with this, I can get green the "delete links" new feature.

my two cents.

iVieL.

Answer (score 0):

The first fixed test is right there ignore the rest.  If your solution looks like the below you are golden. The second idea of moving the entire block above the pagination stuff also works.

```
describe 'delete links' do
    it { should_not have_link('delete') }

    describe 'as an admin user' do
        let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }
        before do
            FactoryGirl.create (:user) 
            sign_in admin
            visit users_path
        end

        it { should have_link('delete', href: user_path(User.first)) }
        it 'should be able to delete another user' do
          expect { click_link('delete') }.to change(User, :count).by(-1) 
        end
        it { should_not have_link('delete', href: user_path(admin)) }
    end
end
```

end